# PostgreSQL ORDER BY WHEN on DOCTRINE

Tags: sql, postgresql, doctrine-orm, sql-order-by

Name  | Sales |   Date

America         |  1500  |   05-Jan-1999

Boston           |   700    | 08-Jan-1999

Canada          | 300    |    08-Jan-1999

Dinamerca     |    250    | 07-Jan-1999

I would like to order in a way where the first record was Bostom and others do not matter the order. How do I?

thank you

ORDER BY CASE WHEN name = 'Bonstom' THEN '0' ELSE name END

Answer (score 0):

It's safer to avoid mixing numbers and text when you're sorting--especially numbers as quoted strings.

```
order by case when name = 'Boston' then 0 else 1 end, name
```

You should be aware that your question includes 'Boston', 'Bostom', and 'Bonstom'. If those are all supposed to be the same place, you're going to need to be a lot more careful in the future.